# AWS lambda read-only file system error, using docker image to store ML model

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am using a docker container image on lambda to run my ML model. My lambda function has a S3 trigger to fetch images. I am trying to run my lambda function but I am getting this error. Can someone please help me?

[image: error screenshot]

PS - now i am aware /tmp is the only writable directory in lambda but how to solve this with that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `/tmp` is the only writable directory in any AWS Lambda environments, either using containers or not.

Having said that, you should move your entire library (during the lambda runtime -- **during container image build time doesn't work**) to that directory -- such that everything remains connected within the library -- and then reference your new library directory in the library path environment for Lambda: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Referencing your new library directory in the library path environment for Lambda should be done because Lambda looks at the `/opt/` directory by default; and since you just moved your library to `/tmp`, you should also update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain that location. This can be done in the Dockerfile:

```
# Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/my-lib-folder/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

or during Lambda runtime:

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/tmp/my-lib-folder:' + os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   # your code ...
```

If there are still problems, it may be related to linking problems of your library, or that you didn't update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @rok, you cannot move your libraries during the container image build time, because the `/tmp` folder will be erased by AWS automatically.

Comment: I want to add that I just faced the same issue and moving libraries to /tmp during image build is not a valid option because AWS clear that folder upon launching the instance and you end up with an empty folder and a file not found error. I didn't find any reference to this in the docs, but I experienced this and my solution was to use tmp folder only during the lambda execution.

Comment: @rok I didn't know that, so thank you for sharing this! I personally never had to move libraries to my `/tmp` folder because never needed them to be writable, but it's good to know that it wouldn't work. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The file system in a Lambda environment is read-only except for the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: Alright, so is it possible to move easyocr (library that i believe is causing error) to /tmp directory to solve this error?

Comment: Hey @Mark, is it possible to write to any path inside a container if I'm using lambda containers?

Comment: @AllanChua Please look at [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html): "The container image must be able to run on a read-only file system. Your function code can access a writable /tmp directory"

Answer (score 1):

That error seems to be it trying to create its config/cache folders and failing. Essentially you need to specify the `MPLCONFIGDIR` environment variable to your container and set the value to a directory inside /tmp that is writable.

Comment: I have tried that but it only helps with the warning message, the error still persists